# Website is taking a long time to load style.css

Tags: css, fonts

Everything else in my website is loading perfectly fine.

My style.css on the other hand takes around 15 seconds for me to load.

The only idea I have behind it taking this long is because I'm trying to load an external font onto the webpage that is 1.7mb. I then downloaded FontForge and went ahead and removed all the fonts except for the few letters I needed.

The size for the font is now 184KB. I refreshed my website and the style.css still takes around 15 seconds to load.

**The problem is, how can I find out what is making my website take 15 seconds to load style.css**

Here is my style.css regarding the fonts

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Gabriola;
    src: url('../fonts/gabriola.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/gabriola.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('../fonts/gabriola.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
    url('../fonts/gabriola.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}
```

And here is the folder with the fonts and sizes

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2TP9K47.png]

Comment: Gabriola.eot is still almost 600KB. Which browers/OS/device are you on, and can you verify that it is indeed the version of 184KB that is downloaded now?

Comment: There are few sites who will provide you information that why and which part of your site is taking time..try to check there and may be you will find..

Comment: here you go https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/tryit and http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ check on that and you will find your solution..

Comment: @GolezTrol I just checked and it's actually the EOT file that is being downloaded. So I looked it up and apparently EOT is proprietary and I'm not able to open it up to delete letters?

Comment: @Leo I used gtmetrix already and they said nothing about font

Comment: You can use [Microsoft Web Embedding Fonts Tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_OpenType#Web_Embedding_Fonts_Tool) to generate a new eot from the stripped ttf file.

Comment: @GolezTrol I went ahead and made new versions of all the files with the stripped ttf file I had. http://i.imgur.com/rQ0L4zx.png the files are all a lot smaller now but my website still takes 15 seconds to load =/

Comment: @RachelGallen You can check out the GTmetrix of the websit here http://gtmetrix.com/reports/periodontalexpert.com/cHmNhUYY as you can see, css is minified and the images are not scaled down but i would only be saving a few kbs and that's not even the problem

Comment: @RachelGallen I understand what you're saying but I don't believe you're right. Images are loading just perfectly fine, but just to make you happy I went ahead and used tinypng. My website still takes 15 seconds to load

Comment: If you look in the network tab of the dev tools of your browser, you should see each request (not only the HTML, but also the additional resources the page loads). You can see when the download starts and how long it takes. Does that shed any light on what exacly causes these 15 seconds?

Comment: @RachelGallen I'm going to eventually be doing those things, but that's not the reason why my site is taking 15 seconds to load. So respectfully, I'd like you to stop suggesting image improvements. Thank you though

Comment: @GolezTrol This is the most information I'm able to get http://i.imgur.com/ekqh6Pj.png

Comment: @RachelGallen Clearly not http://i.imgur.com/ekqh6Pj.png that's on a page without those images

Comment: Is style.css a generated css file? I once had long loading times when my css file was actually an SCSS file that was compiled on the fly.

Comment: @GolezTrol I don't believe so. The extension is .css. Also, Rachel was saying it took her computer 3 seconds to load the page, GTMetrix is saying it says 2 seconds to load the page, but on the preview in GTMetrix, the "Gabriola" font isn't loaded and I don't know what Rachel is doing. If that helps with anything =/

Comment: Pshyoulost please give me the link of site so i can also check and can try to help you..

Comment: @GolezTrol I'm not exactly sure what took so long but I the font thing you told me fixed the issue with the website. If you could make a post I'll vote you as the correct answer

Comment: Happy that Golez solution is useful for you..:) you can also upvote that comment..

Answer (score 2):

Open your browser's dev tools, turn on monitoring for performance and network, and load your site, then look at the results for both of those two things. You can also try loading your site in https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ and see what it tells you is making your site so slow.